# XSLT - Remove Sub Tag from results

Tags: xslt

I am looking to return the content of a particular XML Tag `<para>` without its sub tags `<bridgehead>` or `<sliceXML>` in the results. I am testing the following useing http://xslttest.appspot.com/ Any help is as always, much appreciated.

My XML

```
<para>
    <bridgehead>Galaxy Zoo</bridgehead>
        <sliceXML>Galaxy</sliceXML>
        The human eye is far better at identifying characteristics of galaxies 
        than any computer. So Galaxy Zoo has called for everyday citizens to 
        help in a massive identification project. Well over a hundred thousand 
        people have helped identify newly discovered galaxies. Now you can, too.
</para>
```

My XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="results"/>
    <xsl:message>FROM simpleHMHTransform XSLT8</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="results">

 <xsl:for-each select="//para">
        <xsl:call-template name="para"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="para">
    <div id="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div xmlns:sparql- results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" id="para">
    Galaxy Zoo
        Galaxy
        The human eye is far better at identifying characteristics of galaxies 
        than any computer. So Galaxy Zoo has called for everyday citizens to 
        help in a massive identification project. Well over a hundred thousand 
        people have helped identify newly discovered galaxies. Now you can, too.
</div>
```

My **desired** results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" id="para">
        The human eye is far better at identifying characteristics of galaxies 
        than any computer. So Galaxy Zoo has called for everyday citizens to 
        help in a massive identification project. Well over a hundred thousand 
        people have helped identify newly discovered galaxies. Now you can, too.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="para">
    <div id="para"><xsl:copy-of select="text()"/></div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```